# Grails : How to persist Master Detail Relationship

Tags: grails, grails-orm, master-detail

I have built a UI that allows you to enter a Master Record ( VocabularyTest ) and a set of Detail Records ( VocabQuestion ) on the same form. I'm pretty happy that the data that is being submitted is correct, but when I try to save the Master record, I get the following error

```
null id in vocabularytest.VocabQuestion entry
```

EDIT - The Complete stacktrace is

```
null id in vocabularytest.VocabQuestion entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs). Stacktrace follows:
Message: null id in vocabularytest.VocabQuestion entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)
    Line | Method
->>   24 | save      in vocabularytest.VocabularyController
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    195 | doFilter  in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter
|     63 | doFilter  in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter
|   1110 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    603 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    722 | run       in java.lang.Thread
```

END EDIT

I'm assuming that this is happening as the Foreign Key reference on my Detail record is null, which wouldn't surprise me unduly, as I'm doing nothing to set it.

The Params that are being received by my controller are as follows

```
title: Dave New Test
testItems[0].question: Q1
testItems[0].answer: A1
testItems[1].question: Q2
testItems[1].answer: A2
testItems[2].question: Q3
testItems[2].answer: A3
create: Create
```

My domain Objects are

```
class VocabularyTest {

    static hasMany = [testItems: VocabQuestion] 
    static constraints = {
    }

    String title;
    List <VocabQuestion>testItems = LazyList.decorate(
                                      new ArrayList(),
                                      FactoryUtils.instantiateFactory(VocabQuestion.class));

}
class VocabQuestion {

    static constraints = {

    }
    String question
    String answer
    VocabularyTest vocabularyTest

}
```

The relevant method of my controller is

```
def save() {
        log.debug(params)
        def vocabularyTestInstance = new VocabularyTest(params)
        if (!vocabularyTestInstance.save(flush: true)) {
            render(view: "create", model: [vocabularyTestInstance: vocabularyTestInstance])
            return
        }

        flash.message = message(code: 'default.created.message', args: [message(code: 'vocabularyTest.label', default: 'VocabularyTest'), vocabularyTestInstance.id])
        redirect(action: "index", id: vocabularyTestInstance.id)
    }
```

Am I trying to do something that GORM and Grails will allways struggle to do, or am I just missing something vital?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class VocabularyTest {

    static hasMany = [testItems: VocabQuestion] 

    static constraints = {
    }

    String title 
    List testItems
}

class VocabQuestion {

    static constraints = {

    }
    static belongsTo = [vocabularyTest: VocabularyTest]  

    String question
    String answer
}
```

Comment: +1. Explanation:- Adding `belongsTo` maintains a Foreign Key constraint in the parent object, `VocabularyTest` in this case. But it also adds the cascade delete functionality, If test is deleted, all questions related to the test gets deleted as well.

Comment: This didn't work for me. If I add the belongsTo on it's own, I get exactly the same error. I can't make the change to the List that you suggest as I am dynamically expanding the collection on the form - the only way I can make it work is to use a LazyList.

Comment: You'll have to explain what error you are getting with the list, because I have dynamic lists as well and this works without issue. All it does is change the datatype of the collection (from Set to List). You can expand that list just fine. `[].add('b')`

Comment: I've added my complete stacktrace to the question - it doesn't mean much to me though

Comment: @James - when I say I am expanding the list, I mean that I am adding rows to it on the client side, by clicking an "Add Question" button in the UI. If I use a "normal" list, it fails when it first tries to render the UI, with a NullPointerException which comes from the Lists getAt() method ( if I remember rightly )

Comment: What does the client side have anything to do with the data type of a collection of a domain class?